# installing quantstrat in 3.5.1 version

Tags: r, quantstrat

I'm trying to install quantstrat but it says to me:

Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘quantstrat’ is not available (for R version 3.5.1).

There is a way to do that anyway?
my code:

`install.packages("quantstrat")`

Answer (score 1):

quantstrat isnt available from CRAN. You need to download it from github, so you need to install devtools and then install from github.

Comment: quantstrat as a package hasnt been 'accepted' by CRAN so it's not 'official'. You need to download it from github by doing.

install.packages('devtools')
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github("braverock/quantstrat")